# Laravel returning a leading \n character on responses

Tags: laravel

Every response from my Laravel application seems to be getting prepend with a `\n` character, even when all I return is a number.

It feels like I have to have introduced this as a bug, but I can't find anywhere where I might have done that. I see I have some other applications I've built in Laravel that have this as well (but others that don't) so after pulling my hair out I thought I'd check and see if this something others have experienced.

The issue is that I'm trying to return an ID and use it but it has this leading character.  I could strip it client side, but would rather fix the root issue.

ETA:
This route:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return 'hello world';
});
```

Produces this response:

[image: screen shot with extra line]

It's not an issue for HTML of course, but when I try to assign it as an id, I'm getting "\n 234".

Comment: Sounds like you're returning JSON to a front-end client? Can you provide an example of a method that has this issue and the response?

Comment: I just updated with a specific example.  I'm trying to just return an into to the front end client, but I'm seeing this on every page of the there is an extra return in the raw response before <!DOCTYPE html>. My thinking was a middleware issue, but I took out all my custom middleware and it didn't effect anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all PHEWW! this is a bad issue to end up with.

This can happen when any of your files starting from index.php of public folder to the controller which throws the response. Any where if at all there is a `<?php 
?>` with a new line in between

or

any file involved in route request and response starting with `<?php` is on any other line than line no.1

Check your

1. public/index.php
2. bootstrap/app.php
3. config/app.php
4. any other files under config folder
5. routes/web.php or  routes/api.php
6. app/Http/Controllers/YourController.php

I feel checking these must fix your issue. if not comment below lets discuss!

Comment: You really saved our bacon with this!!  We use the Apiato framework and suddenly found our responses all coming back with properly formed json, but with a "0" as the first character.  Needless to say, we were perplexed.  I happened upon your response and just did a search for "0<?php" and found it in a route definition file.  Thanks!!

Comment: Im glad that you found your fix. (y)

Comment: That was awesome catch... I couldn't even imagined this can be issue. It was one of my route file where <?php was on line 2. Thanks you so much for saving my day or I should say days!

Comment: Thanks a lot man, ended up with a "c" in front of every requests... found it in seconds thanks to your explaination :)

Comment: same here a  'c<?php'  was the culprit. But same code didn't gave an issue other envs. Probably a php setting? or apache / Nginx thing

Comment: I think I ended up having to just roll back about a million commits until it disappeared, but I still couldn't find it in the code.   Meh, it looks like you comment helped many others though so I thought I'd mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it with phpStorm's global regex search:

```
[\s\S]\<\?php
```

In the end I had a new line in the `index.php` before `<?php` like mentioned in the other comments

Comment: VS Code regex search for me was `[\s\S\n]<\?php`. I had an new line in services.php.

Comment: That's maddening. We've been having problems with exports for WEEKS. Found a comment saying it's an unfixed Laravel bug, to `ob_get_clean()` before sending response data. Using that Regex I realized I had two separate routes files with a leading line-break. Cleaned those two up and all our exports (a few dozen instances) are now working without `ob_get_clean()`.

Answer (score 1):

i was getting the same issue and used the following command to see what is in the buffer before returning any data

```
dd(ob_get_contents());
```

it turned out that i have several "\n" in the (routes.php) or in the routes files in case you use multiple files

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel as an API, I would recommend using the [JSON response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses) function:

```
return response()->json([
    'id' => 234
]);
```

This should alleviate the leading line-break issue.

As for why you're experiencing it currently, it might have to do with your request headers. In the past, I've had to add `'Accept' => 'application/json'` to my request headers in order to ensure Laravel knows I always want JSON back.

Comment: Yeah, that's still providing the JSON starting on the second line of the response. It seems like there is a carriage return being printed somewhere in the app. But perhaps pulling the id from a JSON response is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, finally I found it in public/index.php that there was a line of test code at the end of the file, I forgot to delete it. After I deleted it, all thing is good. But it is still very strange that before I deleted it, the extra wording didn’t show up locally but only on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and fixed it by clearing the output buffer before the return in the controller.

```
ob_get_clean(); 
return response($data)->header('Content-Type','text/xml');
```

I have solved it by going through the official php documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

I hope it helps you